# Interface Class relationship in visual paradigm

Tags: c#, relationship, uml, visual-paradigm

I have been working on this but could not find a way to denote the relationship between a class and an interface that is implemented by class in an UML diagram.

My interface and class has following relationship:

```
interface foo

{

    void a();
    void b();

}

class goo : foo

{

    public override void a()
    {

        //Code goes here
    }
}
```

What can I use in visual paradigm to show their relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shown like inheritance. This article may help you [UML basics](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/)

[image]